# Saving data to S3 bucket before the TTL attributes deletes the data from DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, ttl, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am using DynamoDB TTL attributes to delete data after certain time. I am able to save the deleted data by triggering the Lambda function of DynamoDB Streams (processed data).

Is it possible to trigger the Lambda function *before* the TTL attributes is deleted?

Comment: @John Rotenstein thanks a lot

Comment: Hey, did the answer end up working for you? If it did, you should accept it so that other SO users know that it solves the problem. If you had to tweak a few things or if you used a different solution, leave a comment or add your own answer to share that knowledge with others.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB streams will have a record for every change to an item (create, update, delete), so instead of saving to S3 when the item is being deleted, you could save it when the item is created. (And update the object in S3 when the Dynamo DB item is updated.)

Comment: Well yes seems to be a great idea , so the time I update my record with ttl Attributes at the same time i can save those data in S3 buckets. Thanks a lot @Matthew Pope

Comment: I actually went with lambda triggers, since with your approach I had to take care of all the event ("INSERT","UPDATE" and "DELETE"). With Lambda triggers I am handling only "REMOVE" event and also monitoring any Lambda failure by using DLQ . I had to use DLQ , because for any failure in handling the dynamodb stream, Lambda keeps on trying to retry the failed event.